# install packages globally in google cloud platform

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, npm-install, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to install some npm packages globally in google cloud platform each time the shell started.

I added these commands in `$HOME/.customize_environment` file.

```
#!/bin/sh

date -u
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

then, I open the file `/var/log/customize_environment` to see the log output from `$HOME/.customize_environment`

I found it executed and the date is displayed (the first line)
but npm couldn't installed with this error `npm command not found`

`npm` commands are available after the cloud shell starts, so I guess the file `$HOME/.customize_environment` is executed before installing node.

I tried to use the full path: `/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm i -g @angular/cli`, but I got this error
`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

is there a way to automatically install npm packages globally?

Answer (score 1):

The path env var isn't set or active. Use the full path of NPM location like that

```
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Be careful. if Cloud Shell update the version of NPM the path will change.

You can also try to add your NPM (without full path) command at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: now I got this error: `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Comment: The environment is not set :( Did you try in the bashrc?

Comment: what should I provide in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Try it! I'm not sure what will work the best.